# Weird Javascript Regex Replace Backreference Behavior

Tags: javascript, regex

why does the following js expression:

```
"test1 foo bar test2".replace(/foo.bar/, "$'")
```

result in the following string?

```
"test1  test2 test2"
```

is the `$'` in the replace string some sort of control code for including everything *after* the match???

this behavior was screwing with me most of the day. can anyone explain this?

thanks a lot

ps- this is the case in all browsers i've tested

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a regex replace parameter, you need to escape the `$`:

```
"test1 foo bar test2".replace(/foo.bar/, "$$'")
```

`$'` inserts the portion of the string that follows the matched substring.
See the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter).

Comment: right, cool. i knew u needed to escape dollar signs (for cases like $0 or $1) but didnt know what the $' was for. thanks for the link